# If I know the PID number of a process can I know its name?

Tags: bash, unix, shell, process, pid

If I have the `PID` number for a process (on a UNIX machine), how can I know the name of its associated process? What do I have to do?

Answer (score 7):

Did you try either:

```
ps -p <PID> -o cmd
```

or if you only want the command name

```
ps -p <PID> -o comm
```

Or try this one (tested on Ubuntu):

```
cat /proc/<PID>/cmdline
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `ps -eo pid,command PIDNUMBER`

Answer (score 1):

try `top` in terminal it will give you all details of `PID` and Process name